# Select the nearest point for each row in table

Tags: mysql, geospatial, openstreetmap

I use this to find the nearest point

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  ST_Distance(
   POINT(52.760667210533,-7.22646337599035),
   geo_point
  ) as distance 
from Points 
order by distance limit 1
```

I have a temp table TempPoints with all my candidate points and I want to normalise them onto OSM nodes, but there's lots, so I need a single query to resolve them all in one call. UNION wont let me use order by, and my DB raw query interface wont let me just fire a series of queries separated by ';'.
The temp table has lat and lon but can just as easily have a POINT. How can I go

```
select id,NearestTo(TempPoint.geo_point,Points) from TempPoints;
```

EDIT: I can parenthesise each select in my large union query, which solves my issue.

I would still like to be able to join on nearest row.

Comment: "UNION wont let me use order by" - Who told you so?

Comment: http://www.geeksengine.com/database/multiple-table-select/using-union.php you can use it , but nor per query which is what i need

Comment: "To apply `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT` to an individual `SELECT`, place the clause inside the parentheses that enclose the `SELECT`" - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html

Comment: So for every point in `TempPoint` you want the nearest point from `Points`?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
SELECT t.id as tid, p.id as pid, p.geo_point
FROM TempPoint t
JOIN Points p ON p.id = (
    SELECT p1.id
    FROM Points p1
    ORDER BY ST_Distance(p1.geo_point, t.geo_point)
    LIMIT 1
)
```

Comment: that didnt work, nothing comes back from the sub query. my union isnt exactly zooming, its just backend processing . once you have mapped onto The Map everything else becomes easy. But I have a shed load of data to process.

Comment: @MarkLester - Please post some sample data (CREATE + INSERT statements) for both tables. Without that I can't even guess what's wrong.

Comment: I am airborne with parenthesising all my union calls, but the results arent much better than just making a series of calls, I have an awful lot of shape files to normalise and merge. Normalising onto the map solves everything, but I need it to be a bit cheaper.

Comment: my performance woes were all to do with A) not indexing the column and then B) not restricting the nearest search to a small bounding box. it's super fast now I fixed those.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to issue a series of queries, one for each row, and bind them together with a UNION. The mysql stack will blow eventually  so you need to do them in blocks, but 1000 is OK on a default install.
You have to parenthesize the queries as they include an order by. Some points may fail so I label them all with a literal line_no sequence so you can edit and filter the originals. You also need to restrict the query with a

```
WHERE Contains(<polygon>,point)
```

clause, else it will try and sort the whole table, where polygon is a bounding box you have to cook up with GEOMFROMTEXT() and POLYGON(). And of course you need a special spatial index on the column!. Here's some code

```
            var SMALL=0.001

            var=query=points
                .map(function(point){
                    var bottom=point.lat+SMALL
                    var top=point.lat-SMALL
                    var left=point.lon-SMALL
                    var right=point.lon+SMALL
                    var polygon=[
                        [bottom,left],
                        [top,left],
                        [top,right],
                        [bottom,right],
                        [bottom,left]
                    ]
                    polygon="POLYGON(("+polygon.map(function(point){
                        return point.join(' ')
                    })
                    .join(",")+"))"

                    point.line_no=line_no++
                    return "(SELECT "+point.line_no+" as line_no,id, ST_Distance(POINT("+
                                point.lat+","+point.lon+
                                "),geo_point) as distance"+
                                " from Points "+
                                " WHERE Contains(GeomFromText('"+polygon+"'),geo_point) "+
                                " order by distance limit 1) "
                })
                .join(" UNION ")+" order by line_no"
            return sequelize.query(query)
```